# An array of integers in a for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm working on an textbook assignment and am having trouble understanding arrays. I'm looking at a practice question and am confused.

1. Declare an array of integers containing the first five prime numbers. 
   This would be `int[]primes = {2,3,5,7,11}`
2. Assume the array 'primes' has been initialized. What does it contain after executing the following loop?

   `for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
       primes[4 - i] = primes[i];
   }`

The textbook gives the answer `{2,3,5,3,2}` for this...can anyone explain how this loop works?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Your array has index numbers that refer to each element in that array, like a street address refers to a house. Look at the loop: i is the index. Apply simple substitution (high school algebra). If i starts as 0, rewrite the equation with a zero and try to think through what you'll get. There is, after all, a point to learning algebra in school.

Comment: i follow how the how the loop produces the first 2 numbers(2,3) but i don't understand how the the rest of the array is produced (5,3,2).

Comment: The loop is just changing the last two elements of the array. It's not printing anything.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you understand practice 1. For practice 2, the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
```

iterates twice: once at i=0, and once at i=1. At i=2, the condition i<2 is broken, and the loop does not execute.

The actual line of code inside the loop

```
primes[4-i] = primes[i];
```

sets the 4-i'th element in the array to be equal to the i'th element in the array.

Initialized, the array primes is {2,3,5,7,11}

After one loop, the array primes is {2,3,5,7,2} (`primes[4] = primes[0]` has been executed).

After both loops, the array primes is {2,3,5,3,2} (`primes[3] = primes[1]` has been executed).

Remember that arrays are indexed by zero. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

the for loop exceutes two times, for i=0 and i=1

```
primes[4-0] = primes[0] = 2 -> primes[4] = 2
primes[4-1] = primes[1] = 3 -> primes[3] = 3
```

so the first 3 fields in the array are not changed, just the 4th and the 5th

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't understand `for` loops that well at all, since this is a pretty simple example. For loops are basically shortcuts in code that iterate through data structures. You can type out for loops line by line, but they would be way longer. In this example,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    primes[4 - i] = primes[i];
}
```

becomes:

```
primes[4 - 0] = primes[0];
primes[4 - 1] = primes[1];
```

So all this loop is doing is setting the last element of the array to the first, and the second-to-last element to the second.

Comment: It doesn't execute for `2`; that would be `i <= 2;` instead of `i < 2;`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with

```
int[]primes = {2,3,5,7,11}
```

the for-loop works like this

```
i=0 -> primes[4-0] = primes[0]; //array  {2,3,5,7,2}
i=1 -> primes[4-1] = primes[1]; //array  {2,3,5,3,2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a zoo(memory) with a row of cages(array) next to each other. each cage is the exact size needed to hold an animal(data type like `int`)

```
Zoo---------------------
[animal][animal][animal][animal][animal] 
------------------------
```

You decide to label each cage with a number(index)

```
Zoo---------------------
[animal][animal][animal][animal][animal] 
   0       1       2       3       4
------------------------
```

You get some initial funding to purchase animals for your cages (initialize the array). So you buy a Zebra, Panda, Owl, Tiger, and a Bear and put them in the cages. The order you purchased the animals is the order you place them in their cages.

```
Zoo---------------------
[Zebra][Panda][Owl][Tiger][Bear] 
  0      1      2    3      4
------------------------
```

Your zoo just perfected cloning so you are able to make copies of the animals. You Decide people are really enjoying Pandas & Zebras but don't care for Tigers and Bears. You delegate your tasks(algorithm) by having a sequential stack of index cards with instructions(loop). Each index card has a page number going from 0 up to less than 2, so your last index card has the page number 1

```
 _________________________    ___________________________ 
|0                        |  |1                          |
|                         |  |                           |
|                         |  |                           |
|                         |  |                           |
|                         |  |                           |
|_________________________|  |___________________________|
```

You love the number 4 and believe that it is way better then any number and should be the starting point of counting instead of the number 0. So you give all instructions using the number 4 as a reference point.

```
 _____________________________    _____________________________ 
|0                            |  |1                            |
|Yo zoo keeper,               |  |Yo zoo keeper,               | 
|Copy  the animal             |  |Copy  the animal             |
|in the cage that has this    |  |in the cage that has this    |
|card number and put it in    |  |card number and put it in    |
|cage 4 minus this card number|  |cage 4 minus this card number|
|-The Boss                    |  |-The Boss                    |              
|_____________________________|  |_____________________________|
```

Your zoo keeper reads the first index card(with the number 0). He makes a copy of the Zebra and puts in the cage with the Bear. The Zebra immediately eats the bear and is the only inhabitant of the cage.

```
Zoo---------------------
[Zebra][Panda][Owl][Tiger][Zebra] 
  0      1      2    3      4
------------------------
```

Your zoo keeper reads the second index card(with the number 1). He makes a copy of the Panda and puts in the cage with the Tiger. The Panda immediately eats the Tiger and is the only inhabitant of the cage.

```
Zoo---------------------
[Zebra][Panda][Owl][Panda][Zebra] 
  0      1      2    3      4             
------------------------
```

And that is how arrays work for primitives. For Objects instead of cages in your zoo you just have a map that points to where you can find the animals in the zoo. Any animal that is not on the list gets marked with a tag and swept to the wild, freeing up space in your zoo.